# Hyper-V virtual external switch disables my internet connection

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

My goal is simply to get internet connection within my virtual machine (without disabling it on the host).

Given the length - I split this is to different parts, as I am aware some would prefer to just skip the background and get to the problem (scroll down) and see some of the solutions I tried. So I hope this helps and thanks for taking the time to read.

---

**Background:**

The problem is probably something really simple, like the order I am doing the steps, or perhaps I am missing a critical step somewhere, either of which someone with more experience can advise. So I'd really appreciate any help.

Over the last few days, I followed the directions in the below link (finding it the most straight forward) to setup internet access on my hyper-v vm's.

http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-internet-connection/

Again there were many other links, but they were all basically saying the same things with a few useful extra bits here and there. So ultimately below are the steps I followed.

My laptop (a hp pavilion with a realtek pcie fe network card, and a realtek RTL8188E 802.11bgn wireless card) has windows 10 and hyper-v installed.

On the virtual machines I have windows 8.1, sql server 2012, visual studio 2013 and other dev tools.

Next I ensured that using only my wired adapter (disabling my wireless), that I had internet connection. I repeated these steps with the wireless (disabling my wired) to ensure there were no problems with either one or my router (UPC Technicolor TC7200-U). With them both sharing the same default gateway I couldn't have them both enabled at the same time (although not being a network professional I am not sure why, but I see error messages telling me this).

When I added a virtual switch, shared my physical wired adapter. I get unidentified network on the virtual adapter. Below are screen shots before and after...

Before (shows all working, just encase something is needed for comparison with after):

With dynamic (Automatic configuration):

- [Network adapter & IPV4 properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImYnf.png)
- [ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szWLK.png)
- [ping 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1, google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQzyF.png)

With static (manual configuration):

- [Network adapter properties, IPV4 properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oDJo.png)
- [ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbpVW.png)
- [ping 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1, google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSydW.png)

---

**Initial Steps:**

After:

Once I start making the changes in the link at the start, the following screenshots show what happen. I obviously cant connect as the default settings seem to be wrong. So I change them later - but before I do here are the screen shots with the defaults:

- [Hyper-v switch settings used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq7d4.png)
- [Results of adding Hyper-v switch and enabling sharing on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKdYJ.png)

Note the warning message which shows when I press ok in the properties. To which I press yes.

- [The above actions result in these changes on my host Ethernet adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDVAQ.png)

There is no point in pinging the gateway with these default settings as I know I will get a response because the WiFi adapter is working. So the ping will go through that adapter successfully but I still wont have internet access inside my VM. With this in mind I will disable the wifi connection.

Also while doing this I will set the settings in the virtual adapter to obtain IP and DNS automatically for the next steps (dynamic config).

With dynamic (Automatic configuration):

- [Virtual Network adapter properties, & IPV4 properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8kJj.png)
- [ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gySSF.png)
- [ping 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1, google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m43xP.png)

I didn't expect the google ping to work if I cant reach my gateway.

So after seeing the above settings were wrong. I proceeded to correct them to the best of my knowledge with settings that worked previously - as below.

With static (manual configuration):

- [Virtual Network adapter properties, & IPV4 properties (attempted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE4GB.png)

Note above that after I press ok, and then click on properties again, no matter how many times I try to set it as above, I end up with the following actual settings:

- [Virtual Network adapter properties, & IPV4 properties - (actual)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0v5T.png)
- [ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiG9V.png)
- [ping 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1, google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mgaj.png)

The only problems I can see now (with my very limited experience) are:

I cant fill in the correct details in the above steps, but it seems when I put it in on the advanced tab, I could get around this. See below:

- [Advanced tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJWDw.png)
- [Resulting ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vNKt.png)

---

**The problem to be solved**

So after this I then switched back to dynamic IP and noticed I get the APIPA address when I do another ipconfig /all. This shows me that because I cant reach the DHCP server (which is my gateway / router), it is assigning me a temp address. Effectively confirming it cant reach my gateway / router, which we knew from the ping.

- [APIPA address assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl95d.png)

So why cant I reach my router?

I decided to consider enabling my wifi adapter thinking that this might allow the virtual card to reach my router and get the dhcp address it needs. But it seems not. Which would make a little sense considering (based on the error message earlier) that no 2 adapters can access the same gateway at the same time (which was the reason for disabling my wifi at the start - that, and the fact that I don't want to use my slower wifi when I have much faster Ethernet).

- [This is the error message to which I answer yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anB1f.png)

With the wifi disabled I still get the destination host unreachable message when I ping the gateway.

I'm not sure if this helps or not, but I also tried just setting up an internal switch on Hyper-v (so that I could at least access the network from within the machine), but I get the same problem. It cant connect to the network.

---

**Other attempts to fix and research done which so far hasn't worked:**

Suggestions I have read about elsewhere and have ensured are all done are:

1. Ensure virtual box and other alternative virtual environment's are
   all removed (I don't have any other virtual environments installed).
2. Run the commands:

.

```
netsh winsock reset             #this tells me to restart
netsh int ip reset c:\tcp.txt   #this gives some errors and tells me to restart

ipconfig /release               #works sometimes, sometimes gives errors
ipconfig /renew                 #this works only when /release works
arp /d (several times)          #I never get to clear this completely
                                #no matter how many times I run it
```

After doing the above I restart the computer.

I'm not sure what the first 2 commands do. If anyone thinks screenshots of the commands above would help let me know and I'll add.

Let me know if you think any additional screenshots or information would help.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Kronos - How & where in Windows 8.1 can one assign a Static IP to the Host Machine (with an External Virtual Switch)? It was easy to do so with the HV VM, but the static IP on the Physical Host Adapter seems to be gone and cant use it to access Host via RDP anymore. Direction please?